# Where do empty 'natural' Sleeves come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, altered-carbon

In *Altered Carbon*,  Stacks are sometimes transferred to another Sleeve.

*Eg. The little girl who dies and can only afford and old woman sleeve.*

Other than convicts (who surrender their sleeve when they go on ice) and manufactured sleeves (synthetic or clone) where would you get what I call an *Natural Sleeve*?

If the sleeve was of use to its current stack, why would they give it up?

And of it were NOT of use to its stack (*ie:* dead) how would it be usable for someone else?

Could it be that someone traded up and traded on their old sleeve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wasn't clearly indicated on the show.

Sleeves were available for re-use on followings, Some are mentioned in the show, some are speculation and some are from the books.

1. Psychasec keeps an inventory made up of mostly jailed criminals.
2. Slaves from people who have pawned their sleeves for personal or financial reasons.
3. Rich and powerful do 3D print(although this is illegal).
4. And there could be some other methods, not directly shown in the series, yet.

   - human trafficking.
   - Boycott sleeves from storage and or cloning facilities.
   - Bodies from people who've faced murder, accidents, and other violent activities.
   - Soldiers who died in the war(bodies from the enemy, like the battle with envoys).
   - Criminals who get shot and die on the action.
   - selling unwanted babies.

Everybody we were seeing on a regular basis was rich and connected. I guess that would mean the average janitor, if they didn't have the money for a re-sleeve would just be put into storage or something then.

Most important thing to think about is, **Everybody dies, but that doesn’t mean everyone gets re-sleeved.** So actually amount of dead doesn't need to be equal to requirement for re-sleeve operations.

Read more here, [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/alteredcarbon/comments/7vokzr/where_do_spare_sleeves_come_from/)

Comment: I'm not exactly convinced a person who actually _died_ could be used as a sleeve. If their body could function as somebody else's sleeve, they wouldn't have died in the first place

Comment: @Gallifreyan could be some of the unexpected reasons. shot dead, hanged dead, accidents, suicides, natural deaths and who doesn't want to do re-sleeving... a little repair, or with attaching external part for the damaged organ, could make a dead body suitable for re-sleeving

Comment: I'm pretty sure that even in the world of _Altered Carbon_, there's no coming back from the dead with "little repair". For one thing, the brain dies after a certain time without oxygen (which comes with blood, which doesn't come if the heart has stopped or was disconnected).

Comment: I'd also claim that dead bodies are physically dead and therefore beyond repair . But since bodies are probably regarded as property... well, property can be taken away. repossessed like a house.

Comment: @Haunt_House in a sense, maybe.. but i dun think it's as simple as a house